# How to call two argument constructor in istream& operator?

Tags: c++

```
class base
{
    int a, b;
public:
    base(int a, int b);
    {
        a = a;
        b = b;    
    }
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, base& no)
{
    int area, local;
    cout << "Area Code     : ";
    is >> area;
    cout << "Local number  : ";
    is >> local;
    // call two argument constructor;
    return is;
}
```

I've tried `base(area,local);` but after execution the values changes back to 0

I've also tried `no(area,local);` that too doesn't work...

Comment: by the way, your constructor has no definition. is this even compiling? remove the `;` after the constructor and add one after class declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it as

```
no = base(area, local);
```

Or, if you make the `operator>>` a friend of your `base` class, then you could modify the individual reads to be

```
is >> no.area;
is >> no.local;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is not a constructor; it is an insertion operator (`operator>>`).

For your class `base`, you could call it like so:

```
base b;
std::cin >> b;
```

And your operator would be implemented as

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, base& no)
{
    cout << "Area Code     : ";
    is >> no.area;
    cout << "Local number  : ";
    is >> no.local;
    // call two argument constructor;
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your constructor, you do:

```
base(int a, int b);
{
    a = a;
    b = b;    
}
```

Which just assigns the parameters to **themselves**, not to the member variables of the object. In order to change the member variables, you have to do:

```
base(int a, int b)
{
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;    
}
```

The syntax for calling it is `no = base(area, local);`. You **can** also need an assigment operator if your IDE won't generate it for you. It's probably smart enough to do it, but just giving you a heads up.

Comment: If you implement a copy-assignment operator, you need to follow the rule of 3.